# Find all combinations of a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

The list that I have:

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

The output that I want:

```
combinations = [11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33]
```

I have tried:

```
a = [1,2,3]
all_combinations = []
list1_permutations = itertools.permutations(a, len(a))
for each_permutation in list1_permutations:
    zipped = zip(each_permutation, a)
    all_combinations.append(list(zipped))

print(all_combinations)
```

But I am getting the output like:

```
[[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)], [(1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 3)], [(2, 1), (1, 2), (3, 3)], [(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3)], [(3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)], [(3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3)]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be easiest with a nested list comprehension:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

out = [int(f'{i}{j}') for i in a for j in a]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33]
```

The same result can be achieved (perhaps more efficiently) with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20product#itertools.product):

```
import itertools

a = [1, 2, 3]
out = [int(f"{a}{b}") for a, b in itertools.product(a, a)]
```

Comment: Thank you and how can we get only unique values out of them?

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

- you can use a list comprehension to make all combos because you appear to want to sample with duplicates like '33'
- you can use a list gen to do this
- you need to treat the items like strings to `join` them
- you need to convert it back to integer if that is what you want as final result

---

```
a=[1,2,3]

result = [int(''.join([str(i), str(j)])) for i in a for j in a]

print(result)
```